# How can I show centered text in a fixed width element when the text is too large for the width?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an inline list with fixed width elements, each with a label and an image. When one element is 'selected' (by having a selected class applied, the label is shown, otherwise it's hidden. One of the elements has a label that's too long for the width. What I see in that case, is text at the left boundary of the label bounds, which appears off center of the image above it.

What I'd like to do is center the text and use overflow to show the whole thing: basically, overflow both left and right. Is this possible without playing with negative margins? I.e. can I have a solution that will work for any label being any length?

Here's the markup:

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected">
    <a href="#">
      <img />
    </a>
    <p class="label">Entertainment</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
ul li { display: inline-block; width: 100px; text-align:center; }
ul li a { width: 100px; }
.label { overflow: visible; display:none; }
.selected .label { display: block; }
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do what you want... however, if your layout allows for it, I'd recommend increasing the width of your 'li' elements so you'll have enough space for your titles to center appropriately.

Here's a fiddle that may help visualize what I'm trying to say:

http://jsfiddle.net/3AsxH/1/

Also, notice that I removed `overflow: visible;` from your `.label` class; it's not necessary to define it since you have the `display: none;` attribute in the same declaration.

By the way, when I copied your code into jsfiddle, and made the label longer, the text wrapped... is that not acceptable?  If you want your title to display in one line, I'd suggest the steps above.